# Simple database and index help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

I am trying to make a website for baseball coaches to be able to keep track of their team's schedule. I am trying to make an index so that the coaches can see all of their future games. However, the games are not showing up. The background and title are still there, just not the entered data.
Here is my code:

application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 def show 
  @schedule = Schedule.find_by_id(params['id'])
end

def create
  s = Schedule.new
  s.date = params['date']
  s.time = params['time']
  s.location = params['location']
  s.oppo = params['oppo']
  s.result = params['result']
  redirect_to "/landing"
end

def edit
  @schedule = Schedule.find_by_id(params['id'])
end

def update
  s = Schedule.find_by_id(params['id'])
  s.date = params['date']
  s.time = params['time']
  s.location = params['location']
  s.oppo = params['oppo']
  s.result = params['result']
  redirect_to "/landing"
end

def destroy
  s = Schedule.find_by_id(params['id'])
  s.destroy
end

def index
  @schedule = Schedule.all
end

end
```

index

```
<h1> Schedule </h1>
<% @schedule.each do |schedule| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><h1><%=@schedule.date%></h1></th>
      <th><%=@schedule.time%></th>
      <th><%=@schedule.location%></th>
      <th><%=@schedule.oppo%></th>
      <th><%=@schedule.result%></th>
   </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>`
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get '/index' => 'application#index'
 get '/landing' => 'application#landing'
 get '/new_game' => 'application#new'
 get '/create' => 'application#create'
end
```

form code

```
<h2 class="text-center">Add a Game</h2>

<h4 class="text-center">
<form action="/create">
<p>
  <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date">
  </p>

  <p>
   <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Time">

  <p>
  <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location">
  </p>
  <p>
  <input type="text" name="oppo" placeholder="Opponent">
  </p> 
<p>
   <input type="text" name="result" placeholder="Score">
  </p>
  <p>
   <input type="submit">
  </p>
  </h4>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any scopes with a default scope placed on the `Schedule` model?

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the exposed `@schedule` collection object that you defined in your controller in the loop. Instead, you should be accessing the `schedule` lambda that you defined with your `each` method:

```
<h1> Schedule </h1>
<% @schedule.each do |schedule| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><h1><%=schedule.date%></h1></th>
      <th><%=schedule.time%></th>
      <th><%=schedule.location%></th>
      <th><%=schedule.oppo%></th>
      <th><%=schedule.result%></th>
   </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Next time so you don't get confused, you should pluralize collections:

```
def index
  @schedules = Schedule.all
end
```

Then your view would be:

```
<h1> Schedule </h1>
<table>
<% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
    <tr>
      <th><h1><%=schedule.date%></h1></th>
      <th><%=schedule.time%></th>
      <th><%=schedule.location%></th>
      <th><%=schedule.oppo%></th>
      <th><%=schedule.result%></th>
   </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

This is nitpicky, but your table structure is kind of wonky. You should use `th` for header cells only, and `td` for content cells. The `table` tags should also be *outside* of your loop so you're not declaring a whole table for each new row, I fixed this issue in my second example that I showed you. There should also be only one `h1` tag in a whole page.. but that's a whole other area of proper web development.

EDIT: You're missing the `save` call in your `create` method:

```
def create
  s = Schedule.new
  s.date = params['date']
  s.time = params['time']
  s.location = params['location']
  s.oppo = params['oppo']
  s.result = params['result']
  if s.save
    redirect_to "/landing"
  else
    # Error of some sort
  end
end
```

Comment: @M.Overby Define "not working." You should be more descriptive, post updated code, and perhaps resulting HTML source code. Your table does have data in it, right?

Comment: Ok sorry I'm new to this. I found out that it works if i manually type it into the rails console. So, I assume it's a problem with my form. Here is the code to my form.

Comment: @M.Overby I've added an edit to address the problem with your form